# Pause menu in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a pause menu for a game me and my friends are making, I was wondering if js has a simple way to make a keypress function that pauses the game? are they any? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) with the key you want to have the game pause:

```js
// adds an event listener to the document that listens for key presses
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
// if desired key pressed, pause 
// Replace Escape with the key you want to execute the pause function
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    pause();
// else do nothing
   } else {}
});
```

To find the key code for the key you want to execute the function, I recommend using [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/).